# Cómo pasar desde archivo de texto a array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Al tratar de pasar de un archivo de texto a un array me devuelve error. ¿Cómo se debería hacer?

texto.txt

```
cantar sing
bailar dance
comer eat
correr run
```

El objetivo es pasar el archivo de texto a una lista o array llamado palabras[] con posición o índice numérico para poder consultar después.

leerArchivo.py

```
palabras = []
cont = 0
with open('texto.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
           palabras[cont]=word
           cont=cont+1
```

Error:
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Con la función `append()` añades el elemento al final del array, te ahorras el contador y evitas problemas de índices.

```
palabras = []
with open('texto.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
           print(word)
           palabras.append(word)

print(palabras)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema básico es que estás asignando elementos a una lista nula, es decir: `palabras[cont]=word`, con las listas, tienes que "agregar" la información o haber inicializado previamente la misma. con todos los elementos posibles (que no es este caso). Lo más lógico sería hacer:

```
palabras.append(word)
```

Sin embargo, creo que tu código apuntas mas hacia el uso de un diccionario, que podrías inicializar así:

```
palabras = {}
```

y ahora sí puedes hacer `palabras[cont]=word`, en cuyo caso crearas una nueva entrada al diccionario, cuya clave será el valor de `cont` y el valor, la palabra.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer lo que quieres hacer es un diccionario que relacione una palabra con la otra.

```
palabras = {}
```

Un diccionario tiene la estructura `llave:valor` de tal forma que:

```
palabras = {'comer': 'eat'}
```

Se puede posteriormente consultar con la forma:

```
print(palabras['comer'])
```

Retornara 'eat'.

También se pueden agregar datos a un diccionario de la forma `palabras['comer'] = 'eat'`

Entonces, tu código debe tener la siguiente forma:

```
palabras = {}
with open('texto.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        esp, eng = line.split()
        palabras[esp] = eng
```